# Excel Pivot Table: insert new rows, some cells have no formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a pivot table. There are formulae in Columns Q to Z. After inserting rows at row 170 (table size:A4:Z180), I found that the newly inserted cells in Columns Q, R, and T have no formula while others do. Anyway to rectify the problem?

Comment: Did you insert rows to Source table? Or how did you insert rows to PivotTable?

Comment: I inserted rows to source table.

Comment: Normally if you add rows to source table(Table not Range), you should refresh the PivotTable and then the data will update automatically. I also suggest you check the PivotTable source range: go to PivotTable Analyze- Data- Change Data source, please check if the selected is a table or range.

Comment: Can't find PivotTable Analyze. I use Excel 2010.